# Docker - Mount a volume from a container to an other (equivalent volumes_from) in docker-compose 3

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I've two containers : **nginx** & **angular**. The **angular** container contains the code and is automatically pulled from the registry when there is a new version (with watchtower).

I set up a Shared Volume between **angular** & **nginx** to share the code from **angular** to **nginx**.

```
  ### Angular #########################################
  angular:
    image: registry.gitlab.com/***/***:staging
    networks:
      - frontend
      - backend
    volumes:
      - client:/var/www/client

  ### NGINX Server #########################################
  nginx:
    image: registry.gitlab.com/***/***/***:staging
    volumes:
      - client:/var/www/client
    depends_on:
      - angular
    networks:
      - frontend
      - backend

volumes:
  client:
networks:
  backend:
  frontend:
```

When I build & run for the first time the environment, everything works.
The problem is when there is a new version of the **client**, the image is pulled, the container is re-built and the new code version is inside the **angular** container, but in the **nginx** container it still the old code version of the **client**.

The shared volumes does not let me do what i want because we can not specify who is the host, is it possible to mount a volumes from a container to an other ?

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

The **angular** container is only here to serve the files. We could rsync the built application to the server on the host machine then mouting the volume to the container (host -> guest) but it would go against our CI process : **build app**->**build image**->**push to registry**->**watchtower pull new image**

Answer (score 1):

Docker volumes are not intended to share code, and I'd suggest reconsidering this workflow.

The first time you launch a container with an empty volume, and *only* the first time and *only* if the volume is already empty, Docker will [populate it with contents from the container](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#populate-a-volume-using-a-container).  Since volumes are intended to hold *data*, and the application is likely to change the data that will be persisted, Docker doesn't overwrite the application data if the container is restarted; whatever was in the volume directory remains unchanged.

In your setup that means this happens:

1. You start the `angular` container the first time, and since the `client` named volume is empty, Docker copies content into it.
2. You start the `nginx` container.
3. You delete and restart the `angular` container; but since the `client` named volume is empty, Docker leaves the old content there.
4. The `nginx` container still sees the old content.

For a typical browser application, you don't actually need a "program" running: once you've run through a Typescript/Webpack/... sequence, the output is a collection of totally static files.  In the case of Angular, there is an [Ahead-of-Time compiler](https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler) that produces these static files.  The sequence I'd recommend here is:

1. Check out your application source tree locally.
2. Develop your browser application in isolation, using developer-oriented tools like `ng serve` or `npm start`.  Since this is all running locally, you don't need to fight with anything Docker-specific (filesystem mappings, permissions, port mappings, ...); it is a totally normal Javascript development sequence.  The system components you need for this are just Node; it is strictly easier than installing and configuring Docker.
3. Compile your application to static files with the Angular AOT compiler or Webpack or `npm build`.
4. Publish those static files to a CDN; or bind-mount them into an `nginx` container; or maybe build them into a custom image.

In the last case you wouldn't use a named Docker volume.  Instead you'd mount the local filesystem into the container.  A complete `docker-compose.yml` file for this case could look like:

```
version: '3'
services:
  nginx:
    image: registry.gitlab.com/***/***/***:staging
    volumes:
      - ./client:/var/www/client
    ports:
      - '8000:80'
```

Comment: Thanks for the perfectly redacted answer. There is no program running for the client, the CI compile the app and build the custom Image which `COPY` the application files in `/var/www/client`.  Then watchtower pull this new image and restart the container.
The container only run in daemon with (`tail -f /dev/null & wait`).

Comment: So if we have to reconsider the workflow, **rsync** the built app to the server and mounting the volume to the **nginx** container would be a cleaner solution ?

Comment: That seems reasonable.

Answer (score 1):

From your comment:

> There is no program running for the client, the CI compile the app and build the custom Image which `COPY` the application files in `/var/www/client`. Then watchtower pull this new image and restart the container. The container only run in daemon with (`tail -f /dev/null & wait`).

Looking at this from a high level, I don't see any need to have two containers or volumes at all. Simply build your application with a multi-stage build that generates an nginx image with the needed content:

```
FROM your_angular_base AS build
COPY src /src
RUN  steps to compile your code

FROM nginx_base as release
...
COPY --from=build /var/www/client/ /var/www/client/
...
```

Then your compose file is stripped down to just:

```
...
  ### NGINX Server #########################################
  nginx:
    image: registry.gitlab.com/***/***/***:staging
    networks:
      - frontend
      - backend

networks:
  backend:
  frontend:
```

---

If you do find yourself in a situation where a volume is needed to be shared between two running containers, and the volume needs to be updated with each deploy of one of the images, then the best place for that is an entrypoint script that copies files from one location into the volume. I have an example of this in my [docker-base](https://github.com/sudo-bmitch/docker-base) with the `save-volume` and `load-volume` scripts.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The **nginx** container serve the API & the Client and they are from 3 differents registries (on gitlab). **nginx**: Docker Registry, **api**: API Registry, **Angular**: Client registry. ACTUAL SCHEMA : Docker Registry->Client & API Registries->Server. PROPOSED SCHEMA : Client & API Registries->Docker Registry->Server.
Doing it like this will make no sense with the actual workflow.

Comment: @MartinPaucot The references to the API should likely be a config mounted in your nginx container, removing any hard dependency to redeploy a new nginx for an API change. For the angular repository, I'm not following why the workflow requires that it build and deploy an image separate from the nginx image since it does nothing but deploy files into the nginx image. That can be a build step instead of a run step.

Comment: **Because the "Client image" uses a custom one :** the "Angular Image" from node (with `ng build --watch` entrypoint for dev env). The "Client image" use the "Angular Image" then `COPY` the built application and set an other entrypoint `tail -f /dev/null & wait`.

Comment: @MartinPaucot this still doesn't make sense to me why the copy of files into the nginx image needs to be done with volumes at run time rather than a multi-stage build at build time. It feels like an artificial constraint with no benefit that has issues with v3 and will even have issues in my second option if you go to swarm mode.

Comment: Watchtower watch for changes, the **Nginx image** is built and pushed when the **Docker repository** change. The **Client image** is built and pushed when the **Client repository** change. If the **Client Change** i should build & push the (with the new client sources) **Nginx image** to the Docker Registry, then watchtower will restart **nginx container** which serve the application **AND** the API. So the service will be down for some seconds.

Comment: @MartinPaucot if the concern is downtime from replacing nginx, then consider swarm mode with a start-first deploy policy. That starts a new instance before stopping the old. You could also have the service replicated and do a rolling update.